# Java Maze Program Logical Errors

Tags: java, maze

I am trying to build a maze program that allows you to pick a starting point (should be a zero within the maze) and it tells you if there is a route to the exit (denoted by E in the maze from the maze.txt file). It can only reach the exit by following a path of zeros horizontally or vertically. If you try starting on a '1', it returns you can not start here. If you start on a '0' that has no route to the 'E' or exit, it returns "help I am trapped". If it finds a path to the E from following '0' horizontally or vertically, it should convert that "path" into plus signs to display the path. The starting point inputed from the user is denoted as 'S' in the maze.

(Maze.txt file)

```
E0001110000000100100
11100011101110001111
11111000101000111000
00001110101100010010
01011000101111000110
00001110000110011110
11011100110110111000
00011110110111111101
01011011110110100001
01000000000110110111
11011011010010000000
01010010011000101011
01111000101110101110
00001110000111011001
01101011101101000011
11000110100111011010
01110000100100110011
11010111110110000000
01110100011000111110
00011001000011100010
```

My problems from the provided code:

1. When I pick an obvious starting point that leads to the exit denoted by 'E' in the maze, it returns "help I am trapped" (row 0, column 2), which is incorrect
2. B/c of problem 1, I do not know if my function to mark the path works properly b/c I am not able to "find a path" .

The code

```
//Class 1
public class mazeGame{

   public void solveMaze(char [][] maze, int row1, int column1) {

       if(findpath(maze, row1, column1)) {

           print(maze, row1, column1);

           System.out.println("I am finally free!!");

       }//end of if

       else {

           print(maze,row1,column1);

           System.out.println(" Help me! I am trapped");



       }//end of else

   }//end of solveMaze method







   public boolean findpath(char [][] maze, int a, int b)

   {

       if(out(maze,a,b))

       {

           return false;

       }//end of if



       if(closed(maze,a,b) || marked(maze,a,b)) {

           return false;

       }//end of if



       if(exit(maze,a,b)) {

           return true;

       }//end of if



       mark(maze,a,b);



       if(findpath(maze,a,b-1)) {

           return true;

       }//end of if.... Goes left



       if(findpath(maze, a, b+1))//goes right

       {

           return true;

       }//end of if



       if(findpath(maze,a-1, b)) {



           return true;

       }//end of if... goes up 1... ex: row 5-1 is now row 4(which is above row 5



       if(findpath(maze,a+1, b)) {



           return true;

       }//end of if... goes down 1



       unmark(maze,a,b);//unmarks path

       return false;



   }//end of findpath









   public boolean closed(char [][] maze, int a, int b) {

       boolean c = false;

       if(maze [a][b] == '1')

       {

           c = true;

       }//end of if

       return c;

   }//end of closed method. checks if path is invalid





   public boolean exit(char[][] maze, int a, int b) {



       boolean c = false;

       if(maze [a][b]=='E')

       {

           c = true;

       }//end of if

       return c;

   }//end of exit method... checks if exit has been reached



   public boolean marked(char [][] maze, int a , int b) {

       boolean c = false;

       if(maze[a][b]=='+')

       {

           c = true;

       }//end of if

       return c;



   }//end of marked... checks if path is marked



   public boolean open(char [][] maze, int a, int b) {

       boolean c= false;

       if(maze [a][b]=='0')

       {

           c = true;

       }//end of if

       return c;



   }//end of open method...checks if path is valid



   public boolean out(char [][] maze, int a, int b) {

       boolean c = false;

       if(a >= maze.length || b>= maze[0].length || a<0 || b>0) {

           c = true;

       }//end of if

       return c;

   }//end of out... checks if path is out of range



   public char mark(char [][] maze, int a, int b) {

       return maze[a][b]='+';

   }//end of mark... marks path









   public void unmark(char[][]maze, int a, int b) {

       maze[a][b] = 'x';

   }//end of unmark












   public void print(char [][] maze, int row1, int column1) {

       maze[row1][column1]='S';

       print(maze);

   }//end of print method...prints maze, and users starting point



   public void print(char [][] maze) {

       System.out.printf("%-4s", "");//DOUBLE CHECK THIS

       for(int i= 0; i< maze[0].length;i++)

       {

           System.out.printf("%-4d", i);



       }//end of for loop

       System.out.println();



       for(int i = 0; i< maze.length; i++)

       {

           System.out.printf("%-4d",i);

           for(int j = 0; j< maze[0].length; j++)

           {

               System.out.printf("%-4c", maze[i][j]);

           }//end for loop

           System.out.println();

       }//end of for loop  

   }//end of print method...prints maze







}//end of mazeGame class
```

Comment: maze.txt file is....

Comment: Debug your program with a debugger.

Comment: Do you realize how *long* is your question?

Comment: Please update your question with a
[**minimal**, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),
and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: thx @Zabuza nice tip                             Since the comment is too long here a link [How To Get Rid Of These Problems](https://pastebin.com/vj8UB66U)

Comment: Sorry, this is not how StackOverflow works. Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read [Ask] to learn how to use this site effectively.  You need to debug this in your IDE first, THEN ask a question. Debugging involves stepping through the code one line at a time and examining the variables, to find where the behavior deviates from what you expect.  Also, things like _"my findpath method needs to be a linked list"_ are not meaningful questions.  A _method_ cannot _be_ a linked list.  Finally, you're expected to provide a [mcve], not a dump of hundreds of lines of code.

Comment: BTW: where are you using a linked list?

Comment: I appreciate the help, tips, and comments. I do apologize for the butchered post, and I am still learning how to better format my Stack Overflow questions, especially with inserting code examples. And @Jim I will youtube/google a video on how to use the debugger since I am unfamiliar with it. Thank you all for the suggestions.

Comment: please mark as solved

Comment: If it is the green check arrow, according to another post, then I just checked it. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **beg** you will laugh,

hard code to read, but easy to solve problem

in your `public boolean out` you check b>0 instead of b<0

with this, everything is working :)

---

In Addition:

class names should start with capitol letter

i did some code formatting stuff, too. if you want to take a look...

MazeGame

```
//Class 1
public class MazeGame {

    public void solveMaze(char [][] maze, int row1, int column1) {
        if(findpath(maze, row1, column1)) {
            print(maze, row1, column1);
            System.out.println("I am finally free!!");
        } else {
            print(maze,row1,column1);
            System.out.println(" Help me! I am trapped");
        }
    }

    public boolean findpath(char [][] maze, int a, int b) {
        // check current field
        // check if is walkable
        if(out(maze,a,b) || closed(maze,a,b) || marked(maze,a,b)) return false;
        // found exit?
        if(exit(maze,a,b)) return true;
        mark(maze,a,b);

        // go further (recursion)
        if(findpath(maze,a,b-1))  return true;
        if(findpath(maze, a, b+1))return true;
        if(findpath(maze,a-1, b)) return true;
        if(findpath(maze,a+1, b)) return true;

        //unmark this position
        unmark(maze,a,b);
        return false;
    }

    public boolean closed(char [][] maze, int a, int b) {
        return maze [a][b] == '1';
    }

    public boolean exit(char[][] maze, int a, int b) {
        return maze [a][b]=='E';
    }

    public boolean marked(char [][] maze, int a , int b) {
        return maze[a][b]=='+';
    }

    public boolean open(char [][] maze, int a, int b) {
        return maze[a][b]=='0';
    }

    public boolean out(char [][] maze, int a, int b) {
        return (a >= maze.length || b>= maze[0].length || a<0 || b<0);
    }

    public void mark(char [][] maze, int a, int b) {
        maze[a][b]='+';
    }

    public void unmark(char[][]maze, int a, int b) {
        maze[a][b] = 'x';
    }

    public void print(char [][] maze, int row1, int column1) {
        maze[row1][column1]='S';
        print(maze);
    }

    public void print(char [][] maze) {
        System.out.printf("%-4s", "");
        for(int i= 0; i< maze[0].length;i++)
            System.out.printf("%-4d", i);
        System.out.println();

        for(int i = 0; i< maze.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%-4d",i);
            for(int j = 0; j< maze[0].length; j++) {
                System.out.printf("%-4c", maze[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Driver

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int rows = 20;
        int columns = 20;
        char [][] maze = new char [rows][columns];//maze size
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        try {
            File maze_file = new File("src/main/maze.txt");
            System.out.println(maze_file.getAbsolutePath());
            Scanner s = new Scanner(maze_file);
            while(s.hasNext()) {
                for(int row = 0; row < maze.length;row++) {
                    String line = s.nextLine();
                    for (int col = 0; col < 20; col++) {
                        maze[row][col] = line.charAt(col);
                    }
                }
            }
            s.close();
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR. FILE NOT FOUND");
        }

        MazeGame d = new MazeGame();
        d.print(maze);

        System.out.println("You will now enter the row and column # that you wish to start at.");
        System.out.println("Enter which row you would like to start at(Row # 0-19) ");
        int row1 = scan.nextInt();//fetchs row number from user
        System.out.println("Enter which column you would like to start at (Column# 0-19) ");
        int column1 = scan.nextInt();//fetches column number from user

        if(row1 >= maze.length || column1 >= maze[0].length)
            System.out.println("The number entered is invalid");
        else if(maze[row1][column1]=='E')
            System.out.println(" Can not start at exit");
        else if(maze[row1][column1]=='1')
            System.out.println("You can not start at a value containing 1, only 0");
        else
            d.solveMaze(maze, row1, column1);

    }

}
```

Comment: but don't forget to change your way to linkedlist (whyever, a stack would be more appropriate i guess...)

Comment: Thank you so much. I spent probably 2 hours searching through my code where my logic went wrong.  I apologize for the butchered post. And the professor requested that we use a linked list for the "findpath" method.

Comment: yeah, I did not use one because I was unsure how to implement it at the time. I did it that way ^ because I knew how to do it that way, then I was hoping to change it once I got it working then sadly realized I would probably have to rewrite nearly the entire program.